# Embedded Android Device Reading A GPS board from USB

Tags: android, gps, embedded, usb, beagleboard

I have a beagle board that has Android 2.1 on it. We have a GPS board that plugs into the beagle board via USB. I have a app that can read GPS coordinates from a phone but it won't read the beagle board with GPS with plugged in. This is my first time doing this, so I'm wondering where I need to start to have the app read the USB GPS board.

Answer (score 1):

You'll either need to figure out how to get the GPS data plugged into the Android framework as a GPS source, or else have the app bypass Android's GPS system and just directly query the GPS as an arbitrary peripheral.

I don't think Android 2.1 supports USB peripherals, but on a beagle board you are talking about a custom install, so you can use the USB support of the underlying Linux kernel, either by making the USB device world accessible or by assigning it to a unix group / Android permission pair, or by having a setuid native process running as a semi-privileged user which proxies GPS data to interested apps.